# xcode Other Linker Flags: -force_load don't working

Tags: xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

when I want link some .a file to a frameWork file which type is dynamicLibary, I add
-force_load in Other Link Flage;

but when it Compiled, I find some symbol can't be found in .frame but can be found in .a file,  why ?

Answer (score 0):

this it my fault , bucause I set the Symbols Hidden by Default to YES; it will be right after setting Symbols Hidden by Default to NO